# Install referrer campaign not visibile in GA (broadcast sent in android GAv4)

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

lately we have incorporated Google Analytics V4 SDK for an android app according to this documentation (to track install referrers): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#overview

Unfortunately data is not visible in the GA stats even though broadcast is being sent correctly.

I have done below steps to make sure broadcast is received:

1. List item
2. Enable DEBUG for GAv4
3. Uninstall app from device
4. Send email to device with referrer parameter.
5. Click link (play store app started).
6. Clicked install & started the app.

After a few seconds in my logcat following info appeared:

> 03-31 19:52:41.695 24530-24551/pl.onet.zapytaj D/GAv4: Received
>   installation campaign: medium=display, name=promo_mzapytaj_wariantA,
>   source=m.zapytaj.onet.pl 03-31 19:52:41.705
>   24530-24551/pl.onet.zapytaj D/GAv4: Sending installation campaign to:
>   UA-60392364-5, medium=display, name=promo_mzapytaj_wariantA,
>   source=m.zapytaj.onet.pl

Even though I have repeated this step many times GA doesn't seem to show it anywhere (Aquisitions).

Anyone had this issue? Google Play Developer console shows campaign info correctly.

Comment: It should work. But it takes time to appear in the console, have you waited a few hours?

Comment: Yeap, this test was taken 5 days ago. Still no data.

Comment: @Arkadiusz'flies'Rzadkowolski I've also just finished integrating CampaignTracking according to the documentation and received the same success message in logs yet don't see anything in GA. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Arkadiusz'flies'Rzadkowolski , I'm facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.